# Sql query to pull list of channels

Tags: channel, query, sql

I know this is a simple answer, but I can't remember the exact way to write an SQL query to use in a custom field for displaying a list of channels currently on the site. A Google search on the topic wasn't much help. Thank you!

(I am using [Query Field](https://github.com/sjcallan/expressionengine-query_field) to create a dropdown list of channel names, if that changes anything.)

Answer (score 1):

If the site_id is 1:

```
SELECT channel_id, channel_name
FROM exp_channels
WHERE site_id = 1;
```

Getting the `channel_id` and ht e `channel_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a direct answer to your question, but I have created a fieldtype that allows you to select channels. https://github.com/rsanchez/channel_select

Might be of use to you.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work, as I need a custom field and do not build those myself.